# swift: issue with nested dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested

Here is my code and I am getting runtime error for it:

```
var studentsDictionary: [Int: [String:Int]] = [Int: [String:Int]]()
studentsDictionary[studentsDictionary.count]!["Bob"] = 0
```

Comment: Im just trying to add in a new key and value pair

Comment: 1. Please add error message you are getting. 2. You should add your comment in the question with an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that construct is going to be problematic. You're trying to set the `Bob` key for the dictionary at `studentsDictionary.count` (which doesn't exist yet, and thus the attempt to force the unwrap with `!` will cause problems).

You can accomplish what you want with

```
var studentsDictionary = [Int: [String:Int]]()
studentsDictionary[studentsDictionary.count] = ["Bob": 0]
```

Comment: oh. okay. I thought that even it would initialize itself. I guess I have to research dictionaries more. Thanks